# Read large video content list in MERN app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mern

I am developing MERN app which publishers can upload video files and users are able to watch these videos by using payment. But which method should I use to display video list  in short request time? What technologies do developers use for this kind of app?

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways you can achieve this functionality.
In my opinion, what you should do is :

- Upload the video using any cloud storage service provide (like S3 on AWS, cloudinary etc.) or if you are keeping the videos locally then you can use multer npm package.
- keep the metadata like `videoTitle` and `videoUrl` in some sort of database (I would suggest using mongodb, as it is easy and beginner friendly NoSQL database so you don't have to worry about things like schema and modelling too much)
- and then make api to fetch these details from your server (I guess you are using NodeJS with expressJS for backend). You can use mongodb driver available on npm or some wrapper like `mongoose`
- Once you get the metadata from your database, you can use the `videoUrl` that you stored to play the videos based on your some athorization checks while fetching data for the subscription or whatever.

In my view, this would solve your problem and best optimized way for making app which you want to make in a easy and short manner.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I understood what do I do. Merry christmas btw.

Comment: Mention not. Merry Xmas to you too.